# Is it okay to store a laptop for one year without taking any precautions

Tags: windows-8, laptop, battery, battery-life

No precautions have been taken to store the computer. It is sitting upstairs on a bookshelf.
It is an HP pavilion laptop.

I read this [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/11/how-do-i-preserve-an-unused-computer/). I don't understand if this computer will classify as rarely used or unused? The article describes a unused computer as not having been used for years. Is it on the border in between rarely used and unused.

Would the computer be reliable enough to use for school work considering the fact that it hasn't been used at all?

Do you think it would suddenly crash and be rendered unusable?

If it is possible for there to be problems, what should I look out for, and how severe do you think the problems are likely to be.

Will the battery life or the battery in general be adversely affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to take care about battery only. Nothing wrong would happened if it isn't in use even for a longer period of time.

Make first full discharge(**but not lower than 2%**) of battery then give a time for battery to cool down (a couple hours) then charge it 100% level and discharge then approximately to 75%. When it is done, remove battery from computer until you are ready to use it again.

You shouldn't mess up with CMOS battery, it usually works 6-10 years regardless if it connected or not.